# List of virtual machines on XenCenter

Tags: virtualization, virtualhost, citrix, xenserver

We run Citrix XenServer's here, and currently have 3 production servers with approx 10 server running on each. It would be very useful if we could somehow export a list of the virtual servers, even just the name of each- as it's starting to get difficult to manage. I can't see anywhere in Xencenter to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is CLI an option? If so, check out "xe host-vm-list" or "xe vm-list" depending on your XenServer version.

Answer (score 0):

you can also issue from the RPC VM.get_all_records(session), and filter the output of array sub array.

Just really adding this in for technical reference...